# TS Compiler API: how can I get the resolved type of an argument to a function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm working with the TS Compiler API and I would like to be able to resolve the type of the first argument in a function.

I was able to this for a top level call, i.e., wherein the type provided is not itself determined by a type argument ...

```js
interface Abc {
   a : number;
   b : boolean;
   c : number;
}

const thing : Abc = {
   a : 1;
   b : true;
   c : 3;
}

getTypeOfArg(thing); // works, get's Abc type
```

However, I'm having a bit harder time traversing up through nestings, e.g.,...

```js
const doThingWithTypeOf = <T extends any>(anObject : T) =>{
    
   // depending on which strategy I ask my getTypeOfArg to use
   // this either gets any or T,
   // and in neither case gets the resolved ts.Type
   const typeOfAnObject = getTypeFromArg(anObject); // does not work, at least not in the intended way

};
```

Any thoughts on how I could move up the through the hierarchy to find the actual type of the symbol?

Comment: @DavidSherret Would you have any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know exactly what's being asked and confused about what the code is showing. It seems incomplete—what is `abc`? What's `getTypeOfArg`? The title mentions a function parameter, but did you mean type of a function call's argument?

Comment: @DavidSherret Good catch on the `abc`, should be `thing`. I ended up getting the type from an argument to the function in the example below. Though extracting the resolved type of a generic function parameter I believe should achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found an ugly workaround. The function below is an, er, enhanced version of the `getTypeFromArg` which allows the user to change the parameters that determine the `ts.Node` matching in the stack.

```js
/**
 * Gets the type from an arg.
 * @param thing is the arg from which we 
 */
export const getTypeFromArg = <T extends any>(
    thing : T,
    strategy : "location" | "symbol" | "interface" = "location",
    callerPath : string = getCallerFilePath(), 
    rowLine : {line : number, column : number} = getCallerLineAndCol(),
    prefix : string = "getTypeFromArg("
) : [ts.Type, ts.TypeChecker, ts.Program] =>{

    // build the program around the caller of this argument
    const program = ts.createProgram([callerPath], {});
    const checker = program.getTypeChecker();
    const sources = program.getSourceFiles();    

    // get the source
    const source = sources.filter((source)=>source.fileName === callerPath)[0];

    // throw an error if there isn't one.
    if(!source) throw new Error("The source is not avaialble for this program.");

    // get the source 
    const {line} = rowLine;

    const pos = source.getLineStarts()[line - 1];

    let t :ts.Type|undefined = undefined;
    let closest = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

    const visit = (node : ts.Node)=>{

        const diff = Math.abs(node.pos - (pos + OFFSET_WIDTH));

        if(diff < closest && ts.isIdentifier(node) && node.parent.getFullText().trim().startsWith(prefix + node.getFullText())){
            closest = diff;
            t = getTypeByStrategy(node, strategy, checker);
        }

        ts.forEachChild(node, visit);
    }

    ts.forEachChild(source, visit);

    if(!t) throw new Error("No type found.");

    return [t, checker, program];

};
```

Then in functions using the method, you can do this...

```js
const traverse = <T extends any>(thing : T)=>{

    // make the function refer to a new point in the stack
    const [thing, checker] = getTypeFromArg(thing, "symbol", getCallerFilePath(), getCallerLineAndCol(), "traverse(");

    const props = checker.getPropertiesOfType(thing);

}
```

In short, this solution relies on using adjusting identified where in the stack  I should expect the argument to be.

It would be better however, to traverse up from within the `ts.TypeChecker` tree.